# How can I send an email from Java that will auto-expire in Outlook?

Tags: java, email, outlook

I am familiar with sending email from Java programs.  Is it possible to configure the email so that Outlook will recognize that it should expire at a certain time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a header to the `MimeMessage` called `"Expiry-Date"` using the (joda-time) format `"EEE MMM  d HH:mm:ss yyyy Z"`

The other answers are good, but I used a slightly different format.

Answer (score 4):

I believe Outlook honors the, now deprecated, Expiry-Date header.  You can add this to the MimeMessage headers.  The format for the value is `"EEE, d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z"`

Comment: If it is deprecated what can you use now?

Comment: "Expires" is the new one. Defined in RFC2156 and RFC4021. No idea if Outlook supports it.

Answer (score 3):

Add an "Expiry-Date" Header (see [RFC1327](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1327.txt)).

Answer (score 1):

Header-Fields:

- Outlook works with obsolete `"Expiry-Date"`
- New one is `"Expires"` (defined in [RFC4021 2.1.49](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021#section-2.1.49) and [RFC4021 2.1.50](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021#section-2.1.50))